# flask uploads not working on VPS

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-uploads

I am having an 'internal server error' when I try to run my code off my digital oceans account. I have tried run the code locally and it works just fine and when I tried it on www.pythonanywhere.com it also runs fine without any errors.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
@app.route("/")
def index():
     return render_template("upload.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods = ['POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')
    print(target)

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print(file)
        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)
    return render_template("complete.html")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

this code creates the folder and uploads the file to it perfectly on both local and python anywhere but I cannot work out why it will not do so for my digital oceans VPS.

the html code i have used for the "upload.html" is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload</title>

 </head>
 <body>
    <h1> File Uploader </h1>
    <form id-"upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

and my "complete.html" is basically just a paragragh tag saying "it worked" so that I know it hasnt encountered an error..

has anyone else encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have solved this. Turns out it was a file permission problem. To fix this you have to go to the directory where you wish to upload the file and type in:

```
 chmod -R 777 .
```

now the files are uploading without any error